# Enable major versioning javascript

Tags: list, javascript, versioning, jsom

How could I enable major versioning on list? My code is not working and I don't get any errors.

```
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(onPageLoad());
    function onPageLoad() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(enableMajor, 'SP.js')

    }

    function enableMajor() {

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('test');

        ctx.load(list);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                list.enableMajor = true;




            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to enable it using JS?

Answer (score 1):

After you get the list, enable versioning. Then load the list and call `execute query async`

Answer (score 0):

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` takes function *names*.

Therefore:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("onPageLoad");
```

Comment: its still the same no reaction?, my enableMajor=true; dont get updated?